# Finding a records Rank in Database SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, rank

So I need to find an individual rank for a record

I have these results

EmpTot, JOIN_NUMBER, RANKRESULT, STATE

- 524, 21056, 1, WI
- 523, 20973, 2, WI
- 477, 21411, 3, WI
- 460, 20714, 4, WI
- 394, 20974, 5, WI
- plus a hundred more

I just want to have the result be one record, where the join_number is.. lets say: 20714    (rank 4) and show **460, 20714, 4**

I found some sql with the find_in_set, but it didn't exist in my version, so I am stumped. Right now, this is all I have that works.

```
SELECT  JOIN_NUMBER, thestate, EmpTot,
     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY thestate ORDER BY EmpTot DESC) AS RankResult 
FROM    thistable
WHERE   State = 'wi'
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the query above "working", or entirely clear what your exact goal is. This would be easier to answer with such information,

Comment: I need to find an individual records rank in a database table. the below code is great, but I have to make it dynamic now.

Answer (score 1):

Using a CTE, you can filter your windowed results

```
CREATE TABLE [#temp]
([EmpTot]      INT,
 [JOIN_NUMBER] INT,
 [state]       CHAR(2)
);

INSERT INTO [#temp]
VALUES
(524, 21056, 'WI'),
(523, 20973, 'WI'),
(477, 21411, 'WI'),
(460, 20714, 'WI'),
(394, 20974, 'WI');

WITH cte
     AS (SELECT [JOIN_NUMBER],
                [state],
                [EmpTot],
                RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [state] ORDER BY [EmpTot] DESC) AS [RankResult]
         FROM [#temp]
         WHERE [state] = 'WI')
     SELECT EmpTot,JOIN_NUMBER,RankResult
     FROM [cte]
     WHERE [JOIN_NUMBER] = 20973;

DROP TABLE [#temp];
```